# weirdness in clojure map function

Tags: list, clojure

the first strange thing about map in clojure is in following snippet:

```
(apply map list '((1 a) (2 b) (3 c)))
```

The result is surprising for me:

```
((1 2 3) (a b c))
```

Anyone could explain how it works?

Comment: This is a great question and generated a very useful answer (how to transpose a Clojure seq), but the title isn't particularly clear in helping people find this question. I'd be interested to have it improved, if that's ok with @Dfr or others.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`(apply f x '(y z))` is equivalent to `(f x y z)`, so your code is equivalent to `(map list '(1 a) '(2 b) '(3 c))`.

When called with multiple lists, `map` iterates the lists in parallel and calls the given function with one element from each list for each element (i.e. the first element of the result list is the result of calling the function with the first element of each list as its arguments, the second is the result for the second elements etc.).

So `(map list '(1 a) '(2 b) '(3 c))` first calls `list` with the first elements of the lists (i.e. the numbers) as arguments and then with the second elements (the letters). So you get `((list 1 2 3) (list 'a 'b 'c))`.

Comment: Yes, I find the ability of map to zip multiple collections extremely useful. Note that if you know how many collections you are zipping, you can use %n to refer to the element from the nth collection, e.g. (map #(myfun %1 (- %2 %3)) '(1 2) '(2 3) '(3 4))