# How does this code work?

Tags: functional-programming, clojure, lisp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [weirdness in clojure map function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369110/weirdness-in-clojure-map-function)

How does the following Clojure code work?

```
(def transpose (partial apply map list))

(println (transpose [[2 6 5] [1 0 9]]))
```

Comment: @sepp2k: Okay, close it.

Answer (score 1):

it equal to (map list [2 6 5] [1 0 9]),
which in turn means (map #(list %1 %2) [2 6 5] [1 0 9]), the two vectors consumed at the same time, returns:
((2 1) (6 0) (5 9))